# Can i use the same .pem and provisioning file to build multiple .ipa using Adobe Build

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova, phonegap-build

I have two seperate phonegap apps for which i'm using Adobe build ([www.build.phonegap.com](http://www.build.phonegap.com)) to generate .ipa files. I have also generated the .p12 and .mobileprovision(provisioning) file which is used together as a key in adobe build to generate .ipa file.
I'm able to generate the .ipa file for both applications, but the problem is i'm not able to install both apps together on my iPad. If i install only one app at a time, both are working fine but, if i try to install one app without uninstalling the other app, iTunes gives a dialog box saying

> An older version of the app already exists in your iTunes library. Are
>   you sure you want to replace it.

Both apps have different names and app ids.

Do i need to have a separate provisioning file for other app or is there some other problem. Please help.

Comment: I think you already know the answer to your question. You need a different key for each app.

Comment: thanks. i had the thought, just needed to confirm. Can you please be specific about the 'key' you mentioned, is it the adobe key (.pem + provisioning)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's a little different for Android and iOS. For Android you can use one key for all your apps.

Comment: thanks. that was informative.